# How can I show that the sequence $x_n^2$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics

Two real sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are defined by 
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-(x_ny_n+x_{n+1}y_{n+1}-2)(y_n+y_{n+1})$$
$$y_{n+1}=y_n-(x_ny_n+x_{n+1}y_{n+1}-2)(x_n+x_{n+1})$$ with $x_0=1$ and $y_0=2007.$  I need to show that $|x_n|\lt \sqrt{2007}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}.$
I proved that $$x_{n+1}^2-x_n^2=y_{n+1}^2-y_n^2\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N},$$ which implies $|x_n|\lt|y_n|$ and $$x_n^2=y_n^2-2007^2+1.$$

Also I would like to know that, Is $x_n$ convergent? Any Idea?

Comment: $$x_1=-0.99900323990439297512...\approx-1$$ and $$y_1=2006.9999995036057148...\approx 2007.$$

Comment: where from with problem? and why this result is hold?

Comment: One of my friend gave me this problem. Most probably it can be some past contest problem.

Comment: you can also have $$(x_{n}y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}y_{n})=(x_{n}y_{n}+x_{n+1}y_{n+1}-2)(y_{n}y_{n+1}-x_{n} x_{n+1})$$,then maybe use AM-GM inequality

Comment: It should be $$(x_{n}y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}y_{n})=(x_{n}y_{n}+x_{n+1}y_{n+1}-2)(y_n^2+y_{n}y_{n+1}-x_n^2-x_{n} x_{n+1}).$$ Is n't it?

Answer (score 0):

Some idea:

let $A=x_{n}y_{n}+x_{n+1}y_{n+1}-2$,since $(2)^2-(1)^2$
then we have
$$y^2_{n+1}-x^2_{n+1}=y^2_{n}-2Ay_{n}(x_{n+1}+x_{n})+A^2(x_{n}+x_{n+1})^2-x^2_{n}+2(y_{n}+y_{n+1})x_{n}A-A^2(y_{n}+y_{n+1})^2$$
since
$$y^2_{n+1}-x^2_{n+1}=y^2_{n}-x^2_{n}$$then we have
$$A(y_{n}y_{n+1}-x_{n}x_{n+1})=y_{n+1}x_{n}-x_{n+1}y_{n}$$
or
$$y_{n+1}x_{n}-x_{n+1}y_{n}=(x_{n}y_{n}+x_{n+1}y_{n+1}-2)(y_{n}y_{n+1}-x_{n}x_{n+1})\tag{2}$$

as your comment
$$(2)x_{n}:y_{n+1}x_{n}=x_{n}y_{n}-A(x_{n}+x_{n+1})x_{n}\tag{3}$$
$$(1)y_{n}:x_{n+1}y_{n}=x_{n}y_{n}-A(y_{n}+y_{n+1})y_{n}\tag{4}$$
so
$(3)-(4)$
$$x_{n}y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}y_{n}=A[y^2_{n}-x^2_{n}+y_{n}y_{n+1}-x_{n}x_{n+1})\tag{6}$$
for $(2),(6)$ you can have ?

Comment: Consider $(2)x_n-(1)y_n,$ it give a different result.

Comment: if you not wrong, note $y_{n}\neq x_{n}$, then $y_{n}y_{n+1}-x_{n}x_{n+1}=0$ and $y_{n+1}x_{n}=x_{n+1}y_{n}?$

Comment: I beg your pardon. As I can see, In your second line, there is a wrong with $(y_n+y_{n+1})^2$ and $(x_n+x_{n+1})^2.$

Comment: Oh,Now I have edit it

Comment: If both statements were true, then we have that $y_n^2-x_n^2=0.$

Comment: No,because we known $y_{n}\neq x_{n}$,so must  $x_{n}y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}y_{n}=0$,and $A=0$